# Need to get the first and last column based on another column failing to increment by 1 in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have data like this:

| id | days | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 | 1/1/2023 |
| 1 | 8 | 1/2/2023 |
| 1 | 9 | 1/3/2023 |
| 1 | 0 | 1/4/2023 |
| 1 | 0 | 1/5/2023 |

I need my output by be id=1 with start_date of 1/1/2023, and end date of 1/3/2023, since the "days" column stopped incrementing up by 1.

Comment: So something like `select id, min(date) as start_dt, max(date) as end_dt from table where days = 0 or days is null group by id` ??? I feel like your sample data may not represent some of the complexity in the larger dataset.

Comment: Sample data is great, but a [mcve] also includes the expected result.

Comment: 1/3/2023, is that January 3rd, or 1st of March?

Comment: m/d/yyyy, but the date isn't as important as the days incrementally going up....once that hits 0, I want to capture that date column as the end date...I know how to accomplish this using just the dates but not the integer column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

much like Greg's answer, one first step is to clearly define the state we are trying to track, so here I use LAG to get the prior `days` and then ask if it's the first (null) or +1:

```
WITH data(id, days, _date) as (
    select * from values
    (1, 7, '2023-01-01'::date),
    (1, 8, '2023-01-02'::date),
    (1, 9, '2023-01-03'::date),
    (1, 0, '2023-01-04'::date),
    (1, 0, '2023-01-05'::date)
)
select
    *
    ,lag(days) over (partition by id order by _date) as lag_days
    ,(lag_days is null) OR (lag_days+1 = days) as inc
from data
order by 1,3;
```

[image]

but this has edge cases, if there is a null is that column then we can get many valid.

so

```
WITH data(id, days, _date) as (
    select * from values
    (1, 7, '2023-01-01'::date),
    (1, 8, '2023-01-02'::date),
    (1, 9, '2023-01-03'::date),
    (1, null, '2023-01-04'::date),
    (1, 10, '2023-01-05'::date)
)
```

would give:

[image]

as for the 5th (what I was trying to show) but has an interesting problem on the 4th.

Anyways assuming no null values in the days columns, we can carry on.

Now to find the first and last, the next question happens are you want the can there be more than one streak?

```
WITH data(id, days, _date) as (
    select * from values
    (1, 7, '2023-01-01'::date),
    (1, 8, '2023-01-02'::date),
    (1, 9, '2023-01-03'::date),
    (1, 1, '2023-01-04'::date),
    (1, 2, '2023-01-05'::date)
)
```

this has two starts and two ends, but they are disjoined. And if you want the first and last of each, do you want the last last, or two + rows with each start end?

Assuming single edges we use min/max, (or assuming you want the min min, and the max max)

```
WITH data(id, days, _date) as (
    select * from values
    (1, 7, '2023-01-01'::date),
    (1, 8, '2023-01-02'::date),
    (1, 9, '2023-01-03'::date),
    (1, 0, '2023-01-04'::date),
    (1, 0, '2023-01-05'::date)
), edges as (
    select
        *
        ,lag(days) over (partition by id order by _date) as lag_days
        ,(lag_days is null) OR (lag_days+1 = days) as inc
    from data
)
select * 
    ,min(iff(inc, _date, null)) over (partition by id) as min_date
    ,max(iff(inc, _date, null)) over (partition by id) as max_date
from edges
order by 1,3;
```

gives all the rows but them tagged, so you can see how it's working:

[image]

so then you can collapse that down like Greg's answer.

Now if you want 2 rows if there are two batches of streaks, (you didn't ask) but this needs some value to group over, and here [CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/conditional_change_event) can be used, but it needs to be in it's on select context, because it is use a window function results as an input:

```
WITH data(id, days, _date) as (
    select * from values
    (1, 7, '2023-01-01'::date),
    (1, 8, '2023-01-02'::date),
    (1, 9, '2023-01-03'::date),
    (1, 0, '2023-01-04'::date),
    (1, 0, '2023-01-05'::date),
    (1, 1, '2023-01-06'::date),
    (1, 2, '2023-01-07'::date)
), edges as (
    select
        *
        ,lag(days) over (partition by id order by _date) as lag_days
        ,(lag_days is null) OR (lag_days+1 = days) as inc
    from data
)
select *
    ,conditional_change_event(inc) over (partition by id order by _date) as cet
    ,min(iff(inc, _date, null)) over (partition by id) as min_date
    ,max(iff(inc, _date, null)) over (partition by id) as max_date
from edges
order by 1,3;
```

[image]

so now we can GROUP BY that CET value thus get multiple windows like so:

```
WITH data(id, days, _date) as (
    select * from values
    (1, 7, '2023-01-01'::date),
    (1, 8, '2023-01-02'::date),
    (1, 9, '2023-01-03'::date),
    (1, 0, '2023-01-04'::date),
    (1, 0, '2023-01-05'::date),
    (1, 1, '2023-01-06'::date),
    (1, 2, '2023-01-07'::date)
), edges as (
    select
        *
        ,lag(days) over (partition by id order by _date) as lag_days
        ,(lag_days is null) OR (lag_days+1 = days) as inc
    from data
), grouped as (
    select *
        ,conditional_change_event(inc) over (partition by id order by _date) as cet
    from edges
    qualify inc
)
select id
    ,min(iff(inc, _date, null)) as min_date
    ,max(iff(inc, _date, null)) as max_date
from grouped
group by 1, cet
order by 1,3;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LAG window function to determine whether or not the DAYS gets incremented by one. This sample projects a Boolean column named INCREMENTED_BY_ONE_DAY for readability, but it could be collapsed a bit.

Here's a sample table (changed from "date" to "THE_DATE" to avoid the keyword):

```
create or replace table T1 as
  select 
  COLUMN1::int as ID,
  COLUMN2::string as DAYS,
  COLUMN3::date as THE_DATE
  from (values
  (1,7,'1/1/2023'),
  (1,8,'1/2/2023'),
  (1,9,'1/3/2023'),
  (1,0,'1/4/2023'),
  (1,0,'1/5/2023')
  )
;
```

Here's the query that will get the first row in each window and the last one that increments the days by 1:

```
with WINDOWED as
(
select   *
        ,lag(DAYS) over (partition by ID order by THE_DATE) = DAYS - 1 as INCREMENTED_BY_ONE_DAY
from    t1
qualify INCREMENTED_BY_ONE_DAY = TRUE or INCREMENTED_BY_ONE_DAY is null
)
select   ID
        ,min(THE_DATE) as MIN_DATE
        ,max(THE_DATE) as MAX_DATE
from     WINDOWED
group by ID
;
```

Output is:

| ID | MIN_DATE | MAX_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-03 |

Note that this does not handle a case where the days stops incrementing within a window (ID) and then starts incrementing later. If that is a possibility please update the question to indicate that this situation needs to be handled and how to respond to it.